# How to group a Pandas DataFrame by url without the query string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-analytics-api

I have a Pandas DataFrame that is structured like this:

```
+-------+------------+------------------------------------+----------+
| index |    Date    |                path                |  Count   |
+-------+------------+------------------------------------+----------+
|     0 | 2020-06-10 | about/v1/                          |    10865 |
|     1 | 2020-06-10 | about/v1/?status=active            |     2893 |
|     2 | 2020-06-10 | about/v1/?status=active?name=craig |      264 |
|     3 | 2020-06-09 | about/v1/?status=active?name=craig |      182 |
+-------+------------+------------------------------------+----------+
```

How do I group by the path, and the date without the query string so that the table looks like this?

```
+-------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
| index |    Date    |           path          |  Count   |
+-------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
|     0 | 2020-06-10 | about/v1/               |    10865 |
|     1 | 2020-06-10 | about/v1/?status=active |     3157 |
|     3 | 2020-06-09 | about/v1/?status=active |      182 |
+-------+------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `name=craig` section, and `groupby` on the `Date` and `path` columns :

```
result = (df.assign(path=df.path.str.replace(r"\?name=.*",""))
          .drop("index",axis=1)
          .groupby(["Date","path"],sort=False)
          .sum()
         )

result

                                          Count
Date            path    
2020-06-10  about/v1/                     10865
            about/v1/?status=active       3157
2020-06-09  about/v1/?status=active       182
```